# I have this problem where I need to count the number of swaps and comparisons in Insertion Sort I can't get it to actually count accurately

Tags: c

```
void insertionSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i, key, j, c=0, sw=0;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        key = arr[i];
        j = i - 1;
        c++;

        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key) {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = key;
        sw++;
    }
     printf("There are %d comparisons and %d swaps", c, sw);
}

void printArray(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 12, 11, 13, 5, 6 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    insertionSort(arr, n);
    printArray(arr, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry if this is basic or a bad question overall, but I am still a beginner and haven't found any answers online that suited my needs, so that's why I've come here.
Edit: I'm sorry I copied the wrong code, here's what I had from the start.

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: @oão Moreira I do not see where you are counting them.

Comment: There are no swaps in the code shown in the question. A swap is an exchange of two things. The code in the question contains a loop that will move a sequence of things down one position in the array, then insert a new value at the end. So it is not clear what “swaps” you want to count. Aside from that problem, to count comparisons and swaps, set up two counters, initialize them to zero, increment the counter for comparisons each time you do a comparison, increment the counter for swaps each time you do a swap, and, after the sort, print the values of the counters.

Comment: @EricPostpischil So I've edited my previous post, and this is what I had in the beginning, I copied the wrong piece of code, and I always reach the same result which is 4 comparisons and 4 swaps.

Comment: And what is wrong with that result? The way you have written the code, it starts with 12 already “in” in the sorted part, then inserts 11, 13, 5, and 6. That is four insertions, and you have incremented `c` once for each insertion you did and `sw` once for each move-of-things you did. There are four of each, so getting four for those counts is correct. If you want to compare other comparisons, such as the comparisons you do in the loop, as in `arr[j] > key`, then you need to move `c++;` so it is executed once for each such comparison.

Comment: I cannot tell you where to put `sw++` because you have not told us what you want to count as a “swap“ or why four is wrong. A swap is an exchange of two things. Your code does not have anything in it that is an change of two things (except that sometimes the insertion might happen to do that when the insertion involves moving only one thing, but that is a special case, not what the code is generally written for). What do you think a “swap” is, and what do you want to count when you are counting swaps?

Comment: What makes you think that it does not "count accurately"? What do you expect?

Comment: @Yunnosch I see now that I was looking at it wrong, I guess I didn't know what to expect, as I said I am still a beginner, so I am sorry for my ignorance, but thank you to those who answered, I will try to make myself clear if I have future questions that end up here.